# Serialize a class that uses reflection to fill its properties

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection

I have the following code:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class CustomClass
    {
        public CustomClass()
        {
            this.Init();
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                DescriptionAttribute da = null;
                DefaultValueAttribute dv = null;
                foreach (Attribute attr in p.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                {
                    if (attr is DescriptionAttribute)
                    {
                        da = (DescriptionAttribute) attr;
                    }
                    if (attr is DefaultValueAttribute)
                    {
                        dv = (DefaultValueAttribute) attr;
                    }
                }

                UInt32 value = 0;
                if (da != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(da.Description))
                {
                    value = Factory.Instance.SelectByCode(da.Description, 3);
                }

                if (dv != null && value == 0)
                {
                    value = (UInt32) dv.Value;
                }

                p.SetValue(this, value, null);
            }
        }

        private UInt32 name;

        [Description("name")]
        [DefaultValue(41)]
        public UInt32 Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }

        (30 more properties)
    }
```

Now the weird thing is: when I try to serialize this class I will get an empty node CustomClass!

```
<CustomClass />
```

And when I remove Init from the constructor it works as expected! I will get the full xml representation of the class but ofcourse without values (all with value 0).

```
<CustomClass>
    <Name>0</Name>
    ...
</CustomClass>
```

Also, when I comment out the body of Init, I will get the same as above (the one with default values)
I've tried it with a public method, with a Helper class everything, but it does not work. That is, instead of the expected:

```
<CustomClass>
    <Name>15</Name>
    ...
</CustomClass>
```

I will get

```
<CustomClass />
```

It seems when I use reflection in this class, serialization is not possible. 
Or to summarize: when I call Init or when I fill my properties with reflection -> Serialization fails, when I remove this code part -> Serialization works but of course without my values.

Is this true? And does somebody know an alternative for my solution?

It should automatically get something from the database based on the Description and when this returns nothing it falls back to the DefaultValue...

PS1: I am using the XmlSerializer

PS2: When I set a breakpoint before the serialization, I can see that all the properties are filled with the good values (like 71, 72 etc).

Comment: What serializer are you using (this matters) - is it xml? and what problem is manifesting? What is the symptom? How would we distinguish "working" from "not working" here? i.e. "please give us a bit more info..." ?

Comment: btw, the `[Serializable]` suggests `BinaryFormatter`, but "I will get the full xml representation" suggests `XmlSerializer` - hence my confusion; they have ***very*** different rules around the constructor, so it is important to know which; but to be honest, what would ***really help here*** is the 5 lines (or whatever) that would should it not working as expected, ideally ending in "I expect this property to be 12 because (some reason), but it is coming back as 83"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the weird thing is: when I try to serialize this class I will get an empty node CustomClass!

`XmlSerializer` uses `DefaultValue` to decide which values to serialize - if it matches the default value, it *doesn't store it*. This approach is consistent with similar models such as data-binding / model-binding.

Frankly, I would say that in this case both `DefaultValueAttribute` and `DescriptionAttribute` are poor choices. Write your own - perhaps `EavInitAttribute` - then use something like:

```
[EavInit(41, "name")]
public uint Name {get;set;}
```

Note that there are *other* ways of controlling this conditional serialization - you could write a method like:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeName() { return true; }
```

which will *also* work to convince it to write the value (this is another pattern recognised by various serialization and data-binding APIs) - but frankly this is even more work (it is per-property, and needs to be `public`, so it makes a mess of the API).

Finally, I would say that hitting the database multiple times (once per property) for every new object construction is very expensive - especially since many of those values are likely to be assigned values in a moment *anyway* (so looking them up is wasted effort). I would put a lot of thought into making this both "lazy" and "cached" if it was me.

---

An example of a lazy and "sparse" implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new CustomClass();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

        // show it working via XmlSerializer
        new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
    }
}
public class CustomClass : EavBase
{
    [EavInit(42, "name")]
    public uint Name
    {
        get { return GetEav(); }
        set { SetEav(value); }
    }
}
public abstract class EavBase
{
    private Dictionary<string, uint> values;
    protected uint GetEav([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (values == null) values = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
        uint value;
        if (!values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
        {
            value = 0;
            var prop = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                var attrib = (EavInitAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                    prop, typeof(EavInitAttribute));
                if (attrib != null)
                {
                    value = attrib.DefaultValue;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attrib.Key))
                    {
                        value = LookupDefaultValueFromDatabase(attrib.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
            values.Add(propertyName, value);
        }
        return value;
    }
    protected void SetEav(uint value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        (values ?? (values = new Dictionary<string, uint>()))[propertyName] = value;
    }
    private static uint LookupDefaultValueFromDatabase(string key)
    {
        // TODO: real code here
        switch (key)
        {
            case "name":
                return 7;
            default:
                return 234;
        }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    protected class EavInitAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public uint DefaultValue { get; private set; }
        public string Key { get; private set; }
        public EavInitAttribute(uint defaultValue) : this(defaultValue, "") { }
        public EavInitAttribute(string key) : this(0, key) { }
        public EavInitAttribute(uint defaultValue, string key)
        {
            DefaultValue = defaultValue;
            Key = key ?? "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so its very likely the DefaultValueAttribute is responsible for this behaviour, i will look into this, thanks!

Comment: @GerjanOnline it is *certain* that it is responsible

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I can't test it now but its obvious now that this is the problem. Thanks again

About you're last point: I'm using this class as a sort of 'Setting class' that will output its settings in a XML, so that it is possible to overwrite settings. That means I will call this class only 1 time. But you're right the constructor is a bad place, I will make a static helper method to do this and call it in the right place.